# simple_form and grouped select from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How can I create select with grouped options with simple_form from table, not from collection ? Tried:

```
= f.input :countries, 
:collection => [["North America",[["United States","US"],["Canada","CA"]]]], 
:as => :grouped_select
```

but got error: **nil is not a symbol**

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at the documentation on https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form shows that you need a `:group_method => :method` on the collection_select.

Here's the complete example they give: `f.input :country_id, :collection => @continents, :as => :grouped_select, :group_method => :countries`

Also, just in case you didn't know, simple_form has a country_select helper and you need to add `gem 'country_select'` to your gemfile if you plan on using it.

A country_select using that helper might look like this:
`f.input :shipping_country, :priority => [ "Brazil" ]` with an option to restrict the list to just a few countries like so: `f.input :shipping_country, :priority => [ "Brazil" ], :collection => [ "Australia", "Brazil", "New Zealand"]` Those examples were found in the simple_form docs in the "priority" section: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/frames. Apparently, simple_form will detect it's for a country, so just using `input` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, only worked when I used  `as: :grouped_select` and  `:group_method => :last`